# Python - Group neighbor elements into tuples in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list

```
A=[9.6, 7.9, 19.4, 13.3, 31.0, 16.1, 44.3, 16.4, 55.7, 16.5, 66.6, 16.7, 77.7, 17.7, 88.7, 19.0, 101.8, 21.0]
```

It is actually a 1-D representation of a series of 2-D points. The even-indexed values are x values, and the odd ones are y.

**I now wish to convert `A` into**

```
B=[(9.6, 7.9), (19.4, 13.3), (31.0, 16.1), (44.3, 16.4), (55.7, 16.5), (66.6, 16.7), (77.7, 17.7), (88.7, 19.0), (101.8, 21.0)]
```

What is **the most pythonic way** of doing so?

Comment: @kojiro  Mine is tuple. That one is list.

Comment: But not only do several of the solutions given in that question produce tuples, just like yours, pretty much all of them can be trivially converted to produce tuples instead of lists by calling `tuple`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
B=[(A[2*i],A[2*i+1]) for i in range(len(A)/2)]
```

or, as @Igonato suggested in the comments, a neater way to say the same is:

```
B=[(A[i],A[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(A),2)]
```

Comment: I suggest `B = [(A[i], A[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(A), 2)]`

Comment: My nickname and range(len(A),2) are wrong =)

Comment: No problem. But why do you hate spaces?

Comment: They take too long to type. Or I'm used to not having to make code legible because of eclipse's auto formatter

Answer (score 7):

```
In [60]: A=[9.6, 7.9, 19.4, 13.3, 31.0, 16.1, 44.3, 16.4, 55.7, 16.5, 66.6, 16.7, 77.7, 17.7, 88.7, 19.0, 101.8, 21.0]

In [61]: zip(A[::2], A[1::2])
Out[61]: 
[(9.6, 7.9),
 (19.4, 13.3),
 (31.0, 16.1),
 (44.3, 16.4),
 (55.7, 16.5),
 (66.6, 16.7),
 (77.7, 17.7),
 (88.7, 19.0),
 (101.8, 21.0)]

In [62]: zip(itertools.islice(A, 0, len(A), 2), itertools.islice(A, 1, len(A), 2))
Out[62]: 
[(9.6, 7.9),
 (19.4, 13.3),
 (31.0, 16.1),
 (44.3, 16.4),
 (55.7, 16.5),
 (66.6, 16.7),
 (77.7, 17.7),
 (88.7, 19.0),
 (101.8, 21.0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> A = [9.6, 7.9, 19.4, 13.3, 31.0, 16.1, 44.3, 16.4, 55.7, 16.5, 66.6, 16.7, 77.7, 17.7, 88.7, 19.0, 101.8, 21.0]
>>> zip(*[iter(A)]*2)
[(9.6, 7.9), (19.4, 13.3), (31.0, 16.1), (44.3, 16.4), (55.7, 16.5), (66.6, 16.7), (77.7, 17.7), (88.7, 19.0), (101.8, 21.0)]
```

Comment: Your list has to be a multiple of 2 otherwise chops off elements at end that do not fit into a neat tuple.